# What purpose does placing a png inside an svg serve?

Tags: html, svg

A design firm we are working with on a project has given us code and images for several mock pages with some curious features:

1. In the html they use `<img srcset="somefile.svg" src="somefile.png" />` wherever they reference images.
2. Every image asset comes as a png file and an svg file.
3. Every svg file has the following content:

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1600" height="860" viewBox="0 0 1600 860">
     <image width="1600" height="860" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVB..."/>
   </svg>
   ```

   with the widths, heights and viewbox for that graphic.

The only reason I realized this was because I have to fix the mime type in that data url to be `image/png` in order to get the images to display in each browser I am testing with.

Is there any reason for me to use these svg files at all? It appears that the srcset attribute here is being used to display the svg image in all supporting browsers and fall back to the png image in browsers that don't support the attribute. But the svg image is merely the png image with the added overhead of being in an svg file as a data url... Is there some browser bug or something that I should be aware of fixed by this contraption?

Comment: Why dont ask the ones that provided you with this code? My guess is that it's just a fallback if the image dont load, so the design of the page will remain the same

Comment: In my experience, this is a bad practice probably due to lack of knowledge on designer's side. Every time I've seen this it was like: I got a PNG with an icon that could totally be a vector, so I'd ask: –Can you please send this asset back as an SVG? –Sure! (Got the PNG incrusted in a SVG)

Comment: The design firm (well, the client states this is what the design firm does) states "This is the svg file that we save from photoshop for that image." I don't have direct contact with the design firm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in this case the PNG file is a fall-back for the SVG.

But as you note, there is nothing to fall back from, since the SVG contains nothing apart from a PNG Data URI which reproduces the external PNG file.

This looks like (elaborate!) contingency planning for a situation which never arose.

I think you can safely ditch the SVG files (and the `srcset` attribute) and simply reference the external PNG files.

Comment: Just wandering past - and can't help but express some curiosity before I leave as to what sorts of contingencies were being anticipated. SVG is technically more complex (and arguably more memory-intensive, too), and I can't imagine any scenario where it would have been beneficial except maybe compatibility around print (or print preview?). I can't tell there's something interesting I'm missing...

Comment: @i336_ - Pure speculation, but we can't discount the possibility that someone at the design firm was simply pressing buttons, by rote (see: _every image asset comes as a png file and an svg file_) and had no greater understanding of what a `.svg` file represented. In the kindest possible sense: we can't assume that because someone is working on something they necessarily understand the thing they're working on.